# Why do we use plural suffix in sentence with singular subject?

Tags: grammatical-number

I have a question about Singular/Plural.
Having these two sentences:
1.Wann wird das funktionieren?
2.Um wie viel Uhr wirst du kommen?

1.Why do we have plural ending 'en' even though we use singular 'das'?
2.Why do we use plural ending 'en' instead of kommst even though we use 'du'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a misconception here.

> 1. Wan *wird* das *funktionieren*?
> 2. Um wie viel Uhr *wirst* du *kommen*?

In these setences, the ending *-en* is not that of the plural but of the infinitive forms of the verbs [*funktionieren*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/funktionieren) and [*kommen*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/kommen#kommen_(Deutsch)). In other words, they are not conjugated. This is so because there is the auxiliary verb [*werden*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/kommen#kommen_(Deutsch)), and in German the auxiliary verb is conjugated. The conjugation forms depend on person (ich, du, er/ sie/ es, wir, ihr, sie), for example:

- es *wird* funktionieren (singular)
- du *wirst* kommen (singular)

  …
- wir *werden* funktionieren (plural)
- ihr *werdet* kommen (plural)

  …

Answer (score 4):

That's Futur I. The conjugation is in the auxilary verb:

Ich **werde** funktionieren
Du **wirst** funktionieren
Er/Sie/Es **wird** funktionieren
Wir **werden** ...
Ihr **werdet**...
Sie **werden**...